# Irregular shapes as links

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have such elements to code. There are irregular shapes which has to be coded as hyperlinks. One shape and one link. I can't code it as rectangular because of these irregular shapes.

[image]

For example:
"Doradztwo" and its irregular violet background should be clickable. The same for "Pozotale" etc.

Comment: No code because I don't now totally how to cut these elements. As I said below. These elements overlap each other and no idea how to code to how these elements clickable.

Comment: @NewProgammer have considered using inline svg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a rotated pseudo element to split the circle into 3 sectors, then rotate the first and last child to 'fill' the circle:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.section {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
}
.section:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: -5% -5%;
}
.section:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform-origin: -5% -5%;
}
.section:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: -5% -5%;
}
.section:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: -5% -5%;
}
.section:hover {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
  border:10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section">section 1</div>
  <div class="section">section 2</div>
  <div class="section">section 3</div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to re position or 'unrotate' the text, then you may need to adjust the css or add a span element and un rotate it in your markup accordingly (again, using child selectors appropriately).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great solution and very helpful. Although I used Snorlax solution I'm grateful and I will remember this for future.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how your page is set up, use either of these:

**If it's an image**
[<area>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)

**If it's images using <img>**
Just wrap the image with an a-tag.

```
<a href="doradztwo.php"><img src="Doradztwo.png" /></a>
```

**EDIT:**
If you wish to use the <area> tag, you can do it by using this website: https://www.image-maps.com/
Check out this example I did: http://jsfiddle.net/68a5mud5/
The more points you make, the more round you can make it. This was made using a polygon, as it allows you to set points.

Comment: How would you cut Doradztwo.png to not overlap on Pozotale.png? Or vice versa. This is my main problem. Because top part of Pozotale.png should be clickable on Pozotale.php and right-bottom part of Doradztwo.png should be clickable on Doradztwo.png. And I can't do it as images because they overlap each other.

Comment: Let's ask first. Do you have one image or multiple images?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Snorlax.